# Calculate likelihood of element from distribution

Tags: python, estimation

Based on a training data set, I have calculated a covariance matrix and mean vector as follows

```
mean_vector = training_set.mean(0) 
covariance_matrix = np.cov(training_set, rowvar=False)
```

I create a distribution characterised by these values using

```
np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_vector, covariance_matrix)
```

and I would like to calculate the likelihood of a specific entry from the test set, however I am not sure how the likelihood can be estimated in Python.

I have been reading up on the concepts of Likelihood estimation and how it differs from pdf, but I'm not sure how to implement this in my code and any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `multivariate_normal` class from scipy.stats. It has a pdf method which gives you the probability of data points. I think that's what you're going for.

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn

dist = mvn(mean_vector, covariance_matrix)
ll = dist.pdf(data)
```